# Parallel tar with split for large folders

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, split, gnu, tar

I am have really huge folder I would like to gzip and split them for archive:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$1
name=$2
size=32000m
tar -czf /dev/stdout ${dir} | split -a 5  -d -b $size - ${name}
```

Are there way to speed up this with gnu parallel?
thanks.

Comment: I/O is usually not parallelizable.

Comment: Try to use 7-zip instead with its option `-mmt`.

Comment: I am using Lustre parallel filelsystem, the IO is not an issue.

Comment: @Arman The output must still be in sequencial order so even you divide the tasks, the compressed blocks must still be aligned to be processed with split.

Comment: Yes,that's true , probably the best will be get a file list then split and make a parallel pigz of list of the files.

Comment: @Arman But aren't you intending to compile all files as whole, then split the resulting archive?

Comment: Yes that was a first idea. Then if one of the split file is corrupted then whole dataset needs to be done again.:(. BTW you answer is speeding up already about 10 times on 16core machine.

Comment: @Arman About your newer idea, check my answer about it. Since files are compressed separately do you still need to to split them?

Comment: And about your first idea I suggest creating a backup for the split files and doing checksums on them so that on later time you could tell which file is actually corrupted and could be replaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the best tool for parallel gzip compression is [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/). See the [comparisons](http://vbtechsupport.com/1614/).

With it you can have a command like this:

```
tar -c "${dir}" | pigz -c | split -a 5 -d -b "${size}" - "${name}"
```

With its option `-p` you could also specify the number of threads to use *(default is the number of online processors, or 8 if unknown)*. See `pigz --help` or `man pigz` for more info.

**UPDATE**

Using GNU parallel you could do something this:

```
contents=("$dir"/*)
outdir=/somewhere
parallel tar -cvpzf "${outdir}/{}.tar.gz" "$dir/{}" ::: "${contents[@]##*/}"
```

Comment: How would you decompress the files back to a folder. I am referring to the pigz option.

Comment: It seems that the following does the job:
       `cat prefix* > name_of_tar.tar.gz`
then you can untar the "name_of_tar.tar.gz".

Comment: @Arash_D_B Or just pipe it directly to tar: `cat prefix* | tar -xz`

Comment: FYI tar files are not normally concatable, you need to pass --ignore-zeros when extracting otherwise the tar end-of-file block (1k of nulls) will cause problems.