# How to tar files with a size limit?

Tags: linux, shell, backup, tar, gnu-parallel

I am working on taking backup my server data.

Some folders have data around `600GB`, I need to tar it as 6 files for `100GB` each.

I have google it got some idea to do it.([similar topic#1](https://superuser.com/questions/290986/how-to-create-tar-archive-split-into-or-spanning-multiple-files), [similar topic#2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61774/create-a-tar-archive-split-into-blocks-of-a-maximum-size) and so).
we can achive it by

```
tar cvzf - data/ | split --bytes=100GB - sda1.backup.tar.gz.
```

Also we can untar it with

```
cat sda1.backup.tar.gz.* | tar xzvf -
```

My **question** is, Is there any way to do this job parallel (each tar as a separate process)? because it take long time to complete!

Or is there any other way to do this?

**EDIT**
Experiment:

```
# date;tar czf - ../saravana | split --bytes=1073741824 - data_bkp.;date
Wed May 18 09:28:32 MDT 2016
tar: Removing leading `../' from member names
tar: ../saravana: file changed as we read it
Wed May 18 09:51:08 MDT 2016
```

Result

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1073741824 May 18 09:31 data_bkp.aa
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1073741824 May 18 09:34 data_bkp.ab
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1073741824 May 18 09:38 data_bkp.ac
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1073741824 May 18 09:41 data_bkp.ad
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1073741824 May 18 09:49 data_bkp.ae
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  904246985 May 18 09:51 data_bkp.af


# du -h data*
1.1G    data_bkp.aa
1.1G    data_bkp.ab
1.1G    data_bkp.ac
1.1G    data_bkp.ad
1.1G    data_bkp.ae
863M    data_bkp.af
```

This take 22 minutes and 36 seconds to complete!!

Comment: What is the theoretical max? I.e. how fast are your disks? How long does it take to do: `tar cvzf - data/ >/dev/null` ? Are you saving to the same disks as you are reading from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wondered during tar process only one cpu process is full out of four. Tar process only takes much cpu.

So I tried with parallel processing [pigz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557195/parallel-tar-with-split-for-large-folders)

I found two parallel process tools [PIGZ](http://zlib.net/pigz/) and [PBZIP2](http://compression.ca/pbzip2/) , for me PIGZ works great,

For `22 GB` test files ( 10MB files mostly, high in count not in size ) notmal `tar` took **23~24 Minutes**, `pbzip2` also tooks same time(I don't take much research on this) and pigz took **8 minutes**!!! So I choose `pigz`.

Once I have done with pigz, all of my cpu goes to `95%` to `100%`, this makes other process slow, After some google I found a solution to limit this cpu usage,  [CPULIMIT](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/)

Finally I have used like this!!

```
$CPULIMIT_PATH -i -l $CPU_LIMIT_VALUE $TAR_PATH -I $PIGZ_PATH \
--ignore-failed-read -c sda1.backup.tar.gz
```

-i - all child process, important - otherwise cpu process will same
-l limit of the cpu in percentage
for this I used

```
CPU_LIMIT_VALUE=$(echo "$(nproc)*45" | bc);
```

This will give `45%` percent of all core, ie for 2 cores 90 and 4 cores 180 like that.