# How to tar files with a size limit and write to a remote location?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I need to move large number of files to to S3 with the time-stamps intact (c-time, m-time etc need to be intact => I cannot use the aws s3 sync command) - for which I use the following command:

```
sudo tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f - <folder>/ |  aws s3 cp - s3://<bucket>/<path-to-folder>/
```

When trying to create a tar.gz file using the above command --- for a folder that is 80+GB --- I ran into the following error:

```
upload failed: - to s3://<bucket>/<path-to-folder>/<filename>.tar.gz An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the UploadPart operation: Part number must be an integer between 1 and 10000, inclusive
```

Upon researching this --- I found that there is a limit of 68GB for tar files (size of file-size-field in the tar header).

Upon further research - I also found a solution ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304202/how-to-tar-files-with-a-size-limit)) that shows how to create a set of tar.gz files using split:

```
tar cvzf - data/ | split --bytes=100GB - sda1.backup.tar.gz.
```

that can later be untar with:

```
cat sda1.backup.tar.gz.* | tar xzvf -
```

---

However - split has a different signature:
split [OPTION]... [FILE [PREFIX]]

...So - the obvious solution :

```
sudo tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f - folder/ | split --bytes=20GB - prefix.tar.gz. | aws s3 cp - s3://<bucket>/<path-to-folder>/
```

...will not work - since split uses the prefix as a string and writes the output to a file with that set of names.

Question is:  Is there a way to code this such that I an effectively use a pipe'd solution (ie., not use additional disk-space) and yet get a set of files (called prefix.tar.gz.aa, prefix.tar.gz.ab etc) in S3?

Any pointers would be helpful.

--PK

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a non-trivial challenge. Pseudo-code might look like this:

```
# Start with an empty list
list = ()
counter = 1
foreach file in folder/ do
  if adding file to list exceeds tar or s3 limits then
    # Flush current list of files to S3
    write list to tmpfile
    run tar czf - --files-from=tmpfile | aws s3 cp - s3://<bucket>/<path-to-file>.<counter>
    list = ()
    counter = counter + 1
  end if
  add file to list
end foreach
if list non-empty
  write list to tmpfile
  run tar czf - --files-from=tmpfile | aws s3 cp - s3://<bucket>/<path-to-file>.<counter>
end if
```

This uses the `--files-from` option of tar to avoid needing to pass individual files as command arguments and running into limitations *there*.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  As you said - this is non-trivial.

I worked around this by limiting the input files by-date (find .... -newermt <start-date> ! -newermt <end-date>...) and then copying files using the basic-command that I already had.
I too found the -T option for tar (same as --files-from) very useful.